# Subscriber and Producer in the same Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ server running and two spring boot applications. Let's called `appA` and `appB`

`appA` every 5m subscribe a message to `queue1`.

`appB` consume `queue1` and do some data transformation and should send (subscribe) multiple messages to  `queue2` for others applications like `appC`, `appD` consume it.

In this case `appB` is a consumer/subscribe at same time.

I'm using spring boot auto configuration (from application.properties) and at the moment I am reading messages from `queue1` as expected but when try to send messages I'm getting an error like this:

```
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(String, String, Object)" because "this.rabbitTemplate" is null
```

Is possible to have in same Spring Boot Application a consumer and subscriber ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible .

See this codes

This is rabbit configurations

```java
package com.submodule.conf;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConf {


    public final static String rmmQueue = "RMM" ;


    public final static String exchange = "RMM-exchange";

    public final static String routingRmmKey = "rmm_routing_key";

    // spring bean for rabbitmq queue
    @Bean
    public Queue AlarmQueue(){
        return new Queue(alarmQueue);
    }

    // spring bean for queue (store json messages)
    @Bean
    public Queue rmmQueue(){
        return new Queue(rmmQueue);
    }

    // spring bean for rabbitmq exchange
    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange(){
        return new TopicExchange(exchange);
    }

    // binding between queue and exchange using routing key
    @Bean
    public Binding binding(){
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(AlarmQueue())
                .to(exchange())
                .with(routingAlarmKey);
    }

    // binding between json queue and exchange using routing key
    @Bean
    public Binding jsonBinding(){
        return BindingBuilder
                .bind(rmmQueue())
                .to(exchange())
                .with(routingRmmKey);
    }



    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory){
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

This is a rabbit consumer

```java
package com.submodule.rabbit;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.submodule.entity.Threshold;
import com.submodule.service.ThresholdService;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

@Component
public class Receiver {

    @RabbitListener(queues = {"RMM"})
    public void receiveMessage(String threshold) {
 Gson gson = new Gson();
        Threshold obj = gson.fromJson(threshold, Threshold.class);
        System.out.println("recieved object is " + obj);   
  }

}
```

And this is a controller which sends an object on a rabbit queue

```java
package com.submodule.controller;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.submodule.conf.RabbitConf;
import com.submodule.entity.Threshold;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class ThresholdController {


    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public ThresholdController( RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    }


    @PostMapping("send")
    public void send(@RequestBody Threshold threshold){
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String obj = gson.toJson(threshold);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitConf.exchange, RabbitConf.routingRmmKey, obj);
    }
}
```

And this is my transfered object

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class Threshold {
    
    private String id;

    private Date date;

    private String thresholdUUID;

}
```